# Expand UICollectionViewCell to fit to width of a nested UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell that I want to expand when tapped. The cell is just a header that then expands into a smaller UICollectionView. The outer UICollectionViewCell is laid out via AutoLayout (in a UIStackView, although I'm not married to that idea if it's a problem).

E.g.

```
[ -------NFL------- ] -> (This is an unexpanded cell)
| -------NBA------- | -> (This is an expanded cell)
| [Nets Vs. Celtics]| -> (These are cells of a collection view that's inside the expanded cell)
| [Hawks Vs. Heat]  |
```

So as you can see, if you tap a header, it expands and shows all of the current games in that given league.

The problem is that a UICollectionViewCell needs specified dimensions. I know what the width should be (just the safe area layout width), but I can't seem to get it to understand that I want the height to be flexible. I think the reason that this is a problem is that since I'm nesting one collectionview inside of another, the outer collectionview can't determine its intrinsic content size.

Any ideas / workarounds here? The reason that I'm using a collection view for the leagues (the outer collection view) is because I don't necessarily know beforehand which leagues will appear (i.e. they'll only appear if there are active games.)

Comment: This sounds like it would be much better suited to **multiple sections** -- each "league" is a section... when "collapsed," return Zero for number of items in section... when "expanded," return the number of games.

Comment: @DonMag - thank you! You pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to achieve this by creating a multi-section collection view using UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration. DonMag's answer pointed me in the right direction, but for step-by-step implementation, I followed this guide:

https://swiftsenpai.com/development/collectionview-expandable-list-part1/

Comment: Providing a link isn't good enough. Please add the code too.

Comment: The implementation is very involved and even the smallest possible version of it spans across three files - should I paste all of that here?

Comment: This is a perfectly relevant comment to the subject under consideration. No, of course you shouldn't paste all of that here, but we are at least expecting a hint about how to solve the same problem if we ever have it. Try to extract the essential code block that encapsulates the specific solution to your question and paste that in your answer accompanied by a one or two sentence explanation of the code.